# Query on off chain transaction

Tags: solidity, dapps

If I want to use call() to send ether will it be called a off chain transaction?

Comment: What do you mean by off-chain transaction? You can call a function off-chain but that won't be a transaction.

Comment: so ```call()``` can be used for offchain?

Comment: You can execute a view/pure function off-chain. Any change is discarded after the execution, and will not persist in the blockchain.